# Differential forms and continuous maps

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, differential-forms

Let
$$
 X
 \xrightarrow{f}
 Z
 \xleftarrow{g}
 Y
 $$
be smooth manifolds and smooth maps (smooth = $C^\infty$),
and
$$
 X
 \xrightarrow{K}
 Y
 $$
be a continuous map such that $f=g\circ K$.
Let $\omega\in\Omega^p(Z)$ be a smooth differential form
such that the form $g^*(\omega)\in\Omega^p(Y)$ is exact.
Is then $f^*(\omega)\in\Omega^p(X)$ exact too?

Comment: Yes, since the map on de Rham cohomology induced by $f^*$ factors through $g^*$ using the comparison isomorphism with singular cohomology with real coefficients.

Comment: This does not work. The form $\omega$ is not supposed to be closed. So we have no ``element represented by $\omega$'' in the de Rham cohomology of $Z$.

Answer (score 3):

Choose a continuous homotopy $H: X⨯[0,1]→Y$
such that $H=K$ on $X⨯\{0\}$,
the function $H$ is smooth on $X⨯(0,1]$,
and $H(x,t)-K(x)≤\exp(-1/t^2)$ for all $t>0$.

Since smooth functions are dense in continuous functions,
such a homotopy can be constructed using bump functions on $[0,1]$.

The homotopy $g∘H: X⨯[0,1]→Z$ is a smooth function.
It is smooth on $X⨯(0,1]$ by construction.
It is smooth on $X⨯{0}$ because $g∘K$ is smooth on $X$
and $(g∘H)(x,t)-(g∘H)(x,0)$ decays to zero faster than any polynomial in $t$ when $t→0$.

Consider the differential forms
$ω_t = ((g∘H)(-,t))^*ω$ on $X$.
The form $ω_t$ is exact when $t>0$ by construction.
Therefore, the form $ω_0=f^*ω$ is also exact.

Comment: It is wrong that
 the composition $g\circ H$ is smooth.
 Take the example
 $X=Y=Z=\mathbb R$,
 $$
 f(x)=x, \qquad
 g(y)=y^3, \qquad
 K(x)=x^{1/3}.
 $$
 Consider the derivative $D(x,t)=(\partial/\partial x)g(H(x,t))$.
 For $t=0$,
 $D(x,t)=f'(x)=1$.
 For each small $t>0$,
 there exists $x_0\in[-1,1]\subseteq X$ such that $H(x_0,t)=0$.
 Then $D(x_0,t)=g'(0)(\partial/\partial x)|_{x=x_0}H(x,t)=0$.
 Thus the derivative $D(x,t)$ is not continuous,
 and so the composition $g\circ H$ is not smooth.